# C++ Insert integer nodes into a templated singly linked list class in ascending order - Homework

Tags: c++, class, templates, insert, singly-linked-list

I'm been having trouble with either my constructor or my insert function, I'm not sure which is the issue, but the real issue is that I get the error code mentioning I'm having an error with things getting de-referenced. All I'm trying to do is insert a node containing an integer value in the correct position.

This is the declaration:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    template <class T>
    struct Node
    {
        T       mData;
        Node<T> *mNext;

        /*      Pre:  None
        *     Post:  This object is initialized using default values
        *  Purpose:  To initialize date object
        *************************************************************************/
        Node()
        {
            mData = T();
            mNext = NULL;
        }


        /*      Pre:  None
        *     Post:  This object is initialized using specified data
        *  Purpose:  To intialize date object
        *************************************************************************/
        Node(T data, Node<T>* next)
        {
            mData = data;
            mNext = next;
        }
    };


private:
    Node<T> *mHead;
    int     mCount;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    int  getCount();
    T    getData(int index);
    void setData(int index, T data);

    void clear();
    void display();
    bool insert(T data);
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isExist(T searchKey);
    bool remove(T searchKey);
    T    removeAt(int index);

    T operator[](int index);
    void operator=(LinkedList<T> *list);
};
```

And this is the insert:

```
template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
    Node<T>* current = mHead;

    if (!current)
    {
        if (mCount == 0)
        {
            current->mData = data;
        }
        else
        {
            while (current->mNext != NULL)
            {
                if (current->mData == data)
                    return false;
                else if (current->mNext->mData < data)
                {
                    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>();
                    newNode->mData = data;

                    newNode->mNext = current->mNext;

                    current->mNext = newNode;
                }

                current = current->mNext;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>(data, NULL);

        current->mNext = node;
    }

    mCount++;

    return true;
}
```

Every time my program breaks, it's at this line

```
current->mData = data;
```

Comment: Is your intent to only allow **unique** values in the list (which would make it a **set**; not just a list), or simply to insert them in sorted order (allowing uniques) ?

Comment: Yes, this is intended to be creating sets. Because the goal of the homework was to do A union B, A intersection B, A difference B, and B difference A

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare `Node` class as template, in fact you should get a compile error message like `error: declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter`.

Remove `template<class T>` from `Node` and change `Node<T>` to `Node` throughout the code.